# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension - Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am using

```
  ruby 1.9.3p547 (2014-05-14 revision 45962)
  Rails 4.1.6
```

when I try to upgrade bcrypt

```
gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.9
```

or

```
gem install bcrypt
```

I am getting an error

```
make
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.o] Segmentation fault: 11

make failed, exit code 2
```

Any thoughts how to fix that please?

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/igor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.o] Segmentation fault: 11

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/igor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/bcrypt-3.1.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/igor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/1.9.1/bcrypt-3.1.9/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: please show the full log

Comment: please show the `gem_make.out`

Comment: it is just what it says in the question : "creating Makefile

make  clean

make
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.o] Segmentation fault: 11

make failed, exit code 2"

Comment: try to change default compiler

Comment: @simone carletti did you ever solve this? i'm running into the same problem.